# How to update time of day in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM memberships 
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM expired_at) = 0 
  AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM expired_at) = 15;
```

I need to `UPDATE` all those records to be `08:00:00`

So for example, if a record is `2016-06-15 00:00:00`, I want to change it to `2016-06-15 08:00:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
update memberships
   set expired_at = expired_at::date + time '08:00:00'
where extract(hour from expired_at) = 0
  and extract(day from expired_at) = 15
```

`expired_at::date` will create a date without a time and then the time is simply added.